# Julia - creating matrices of Union{Nothing,String} vs Union{Nothing,Bool}

Tags: julia

In a program I have, I want to initialise a bunch of matrices with `Nothing` and then if some condition is met, change individual elements to a value of type `Bool` or `String`

This works fine when I initialise with

```
Array{Union{Nothing,Bool},2}(undef,5,5)
```

which yields something looking like

```
5×5 Matrix{Union{Nothing, Bool}}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
```

But not when I initialise with

```
Array{Union{Nothing,String},2}(undef,5,5)
```

which gives me

```
5×5 Matrix{Union{Nothing, String}}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
```

Now I can change values in that second array to `String`s so that I get

```
5×5 Matrix{Union{Nothing, String}}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef     "Look"
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
```

But when I have a second large array constructed as

```
Array{Union{Nothing, Bool, String}}(undef,10,5)
```

which looks like

```
10×5 Matrix{Union{Nothing, Bool, String}}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
```

I can assign the first 5 rows quite happily to the first array constructed out of `Nothing` and `Bool`, but I can't assign to the second matrix constructed out of `#undef`/`nothing` and `String`.  Instead, I get this error

```
UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
```

Initially I thought it was something to do with converting from type `Nothing` or `#undef` to `String` but I seem to be able to do this when I assign individual strings up above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let me start with a recommendation, what to do.

It is best to create your matrices in general in the following way:

```
julia> Array{Union{Nothing,String},2}(nothing,5,5)
5×5 Matrix{Union{Nothing, String}}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
```

In this way you ensure that they are properly initialized.

Now to explain what you observe. `#undef` as opposed to `nothing` is not a value. It means that the given cell in a matrix is not connected to any value. You cannot read from such a cell. You must first write to it before you can read it:

```
julia> x = Vector{String}(undef, 3)
3-element Vector{String}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> x[1]
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(A::Vector{String}, i1::Int64)
   @ Base .\array.jl:801
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[6]:1

julia> x[1] = "a"
"a"

julia> x
3-element Vector{String}:
    "a"
 #undef
 #undef

julia> x[1]
"a"
```

You might ask why for the case of `Union{Bool, Nothing}` element type you get a value in an array, while in the case of `Union{String, Nothing}` you do get `#undef`, i.e. no value that you can read.

The answer is that in Julia there are two kinds of types:

- bits type, for which `isbitstype` function returns `true`; such data are immutable and do not contain references to other values; an example of such data is `Bool`
- non-bits type, which either are mutable, or contain references; an example of such data is `String` (as technically string is represented as a reference to some location in memory where the contents of the string is stored)

As you can see here:

```
julia> isbitstype(Bool)
true

julia> isbitstype(String)
false
```

Now - if your array is to store a bits type (or their union) then it stores it directly, so there is always some value (there is no guarantee what value it would be but you know you will get a value), e.g.:

```
julia> Matrix{Int}(undef, 5, 5)
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 260255120  260384864  260235344  260254240  0
 260254240  260235344  260235344  260255120  0
 261849744  260235344  260235344  260235344  0
 260465792  260465440  260464224  260235344  0
 260235344  260235344  260235344  260235344  0
```

and as you can see we have some values stored in it, but it is undefined what the values would be.

On the other hand if your array is to store a non-bits type it actually stores references to the values. Which means that when you create an array of such values without initializing it you get `#undef` - which means that in this cell there is no reference to a valid value.

Just to show you that it has nothing to do directly with strings, let me show you e.g. the `String7` type (it is exported e.g. by CSV.jl), which is a fixed width string (maximum width of 7 bytes) that is a bits type. Observe the difference:

```
julia> using CSV

julia> isbitstype(String7)
true

julia> Matrix{String7}(undef, 5, 5)
5×5 Matrix{String7}:
 "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  …  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
 "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"     "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
 "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"     "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
 "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"     "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
 "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"  "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"     "\0\0\0\0\x0f\x86_\x10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

julia> Matrix{String}(undef, 5, 5)
5×5 Matrix{String}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
```

In the first case you got a matrix of `String7` values that is initialized, but the values it is initialized to are undefined (it is some garbage).
In the second case you got a matrix of `String` values, and since they are non-bits the matrix is uninitialized - it does not hold any values yet. You first have to assign some values before you will be able to read them.

Finally there is a `isassigned` function that allows you to check if the container has a value associated with some index (i.e. to check if it is not `#undef` or the index is out of bounds). Here is an example:

```
julia> x = Vector{String}(undef, 3)
3-element Vector{String}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> x[1] = "a"
"a"

julia> isassigned(x, 1) # we have a value here
true

julia> isassigned(x, 2) # no value
false

julia> isassigned(x, 3) # no value
false

julia> isassigned(x, 4) # out of bounds
false
```

If anything is unclear please comment and I can expand the answer.

Comment: This is a superbly detailed answer and it thoroughly deepens my understanding.  Thank you.